Convert a string literal to a float in Python
I have a string:
"0xFF"
How do I convert it to a float type?
I tried
"0xFF".fromhex()

and that does not seem to exist.

What is desired output for shown input?

The desired output is a float type

Yes, but is 0xFF supposed to be 255.0, -1.0, something else?

You need to call fromhex() on float, not on your string.
The following will work:
float.fromhex("0xFF")  # Will produce 255.0

Although it isn't clear (to me) from the docs, it seems like the hex prefix 0x can be omitted, and the following will also work:
float.fromhex("FF")  # Will produce 255.0


You can try
int("0xFF", 16)

for float:
float(int("0xFF", 16))

output
255.0


fromhex() method expects a float-compatible hex representation (like "0x1.921fb54442d18p+1"). However, convert the hex string to an integer and cast it to a float.
hex_string = "0xFF"
integer_value = int(hex_string, 16)
float_value = float(integer_value)

print(float_value)

In this example, the hexadecimal value "0xFF" is converted to an integer (255) and casted to a float (255.0).
